# How to create a dropdown clickable checklist that fills an Excell cell?

Tags: excel

I have a single cell A2 that needs to be filled with a string that's one or more items from a given list with 20 items. We have to manually input these values in alphabetic order separated by ";".

Is there a way that we can have a dropdown list on cell A2, that we could pick these values from a checklist, and by clicking on them, they would get inserted?

If so, how can I have this and use it for several rows (A2-A366) where each row is a different data entry for another day but with the same logic?

Answer (score 1):

**Create a Drop-down List**

To create a drop-down list in Excel, execute the following steps.

**1.** On the second sheet, type the items you want to appear in the drop-down list.

[image]

Note: if you don't want users to access the items on Sheet2, you can hide Sheet2. To achieve this, right click on the sheet tab of Sheet2 and click on Hide.

**2.** On the first sheet, select cell B1.

[image]

**3.** On the Data tab, in the Data Tools group, click Data Validation.

[image]

The 'Data Validation' dialog box appears.

**4.** In the Allow box, click List.

**5.** Click in the Source box and select the range A1:A3 on Sheet2.

[image]

**6.** Click OK.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for following up.

I'm not asking how to create a normal dropdown list where you can only have 1 option. I want to have a list with 20 items where I can click in 1 or more elements and they get added in the string.

So if the list has A B C D E F G H I J K,

I want to be able to click on A B C

And cell B2 would be "A;B;C"

Comment: You need [Dynamic drop down list](https://www.excelcampus.com/tips/dynamic-data-validation/).

Comment: Hello HafizSh, 
I need something like this https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3922-excel-drop-down-list-with-checkboxes.html.

However, this link is only for one cell. I needed this to replicate for 200-300 cells.

Comment: I would suggest you to post new question with complete details @GL_99
you will have an answer.